# How to share variables between different m files in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have three m files using the same variables and carrying out calculations on these variables. I have made an index m file in which i have declared all the variables and I can share the variables to the remaining m files using the variable names. My problem is that the variable names change too often and then I have to change the variable names in all these files manually. How can I make a Matlab script which can automatically get the variable names and value from  the index m file and put these to the remaining m files.

Comment: One solution can be by using functions and using variables as arguments to these functions. How can this be done efficiently?

Comment: the classic solution to this issue is to create the other .m files as functions. so you run your script in myfile.m and inside that you call your myfile2.m as myfile2(). can you post a little example of the code

Comment: This ia a portion of my m file
% close all;
clear all;
clc;

A0=0;
A1=6;
A2=12;
A3=13;
save('exp.mat', 'A0','A1', 'A2', 'A3');
I know that this is not an efficient way of sharing data. But I am new to functions. How can I use functions? Can you give me a startup?

Comment: ah ok, i feel like this is one of the files and you set the other A in an other right? there are a few things that should be adressed here: are all of those  'A' numbers or are there strings too? and do you want to create/edit them in different files and save them in the end?  what other tasks have to be done in those files?

Comment: @Finn. yes you are right. I assign the variables in this file and once in the work space I can use them in other files since I run the files one by one.  All the variables are numbers.  The different m files perform calculations and plot the graphs. I don't want to edit them in different files. Once the variables are passed and calculations performed, the results are saved automatically. I want to pass the variables efficiently.

Comment: @Habib.Khan You should probably get a lot out from reading the [basics](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf). Apart from this, using functions is not _one_ solution, but _the_ solution. In general it would be accurate to say that you should always use functions.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you just need a little example from where you could go on so here we go:
First calling each value with a different variable name. if you have a lot of values of the same type a array is easier like:

```
A0=0; A1=6; A2=12 %each one with its own name 
B=zeros(16,1); %create an array of 16 numbers
B(1)= 0; %1 is the first element of an array so care for A0
B(2)= 6;
B(8)= 12;
disp(B); % a lot of numbers and you can each address individually
disp(B(8)); %-> 12
```

you can put all that in your script and try it. Now to the function part. Your function can have input, output, neither or both. If you just want to create data you wont need an input but an output.

save this as `myfile1.m`:

```
function output = myfile1()

number=[3;5;6]; %same as number(1)=3;number(2)=5;number(3)=6
%all the names just stay in this function and the variable name is chosen in the script
output = number; %output is what the file will be

end
```

and this as `myfile2.m`

```
function output = myfile2(input)

input=input*2;%double all the numbers 
%This will make an error if "input" is not an array with at least 3
%elements
input(3)=input(3)+2; %only input(3) + 2; 
output = input;

end
```

and now try

```
B=myfile1() %B will become the output of myfile1
C=myfile2(B) %B is the input of myfile2 and C will become the output
save('exp.mat','C')
```

I hope this will get you started.